# How to implement Maximum Diversification in R?

Tags: programming, optimization

I am trying to code up the optimization problem for Max Diversification Portfolios.

The main problem I am having is properly translating the objective function in to code and port it in to the optimizer in general.

How would one approach this? Can this be solved with R's `quadprog`?

The objective function to maximize is the diversification ratio:

```
d(P) = P'E / sqrt(P'VP)
```

Where:

- `E` is vector of asset volatilities,
- `P` is the vector of weights
- `V` is the covariance matrix.

Comment: I doubt you are a professional quant, but I'll answer this because I think it can be interesting for other users. Please read the [faq] again though, and consider completing your user data.

Comment: It would be nice if you could accept one of the answers - Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the full R source code for that at the site of [Systematic Investor](http://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com).

For example have a look at this post about [Maximum Sharpe Portfolios](http://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/maximum-sharpe-portfolio/). There you see that he created the helper function `portfolio.allocation.helper` for the following optimization methods:

```
EW=equal.weight.portfolio,
RP=risk.parity.portfolio,
MV=min.var.portfolio,
MD=max.div.portfolio,
MC=min.corr.portfolio,
MC2=min.corr2.portfolio,
MCE=min.corr.excel.portfolio,
MS=max.sharpe.portfolio
```

Now the full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/blob/master/R/strategy.r).

You'll want to have a look at `max.div.portfolio` which is based on the method in:

> Toward Maximum Diversification by Y. Choueifaty, Y. Coignard, The
>   Journal of Portfolio Management, Fall 2008, Vol. 35, No. 1: pp. 40-51

Answer (score 4):

For the record, the formula for maximum diversification portfolio can be found in this [paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1977577).

As you can see from the `quadprog` [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/quadprog.pdf), it minimizes problems of the following form:

$$ \min - d'b + \tfrac12 b' D b ~ \text{with} ~ A' b \geq b_0 $$

So clearly, it's not good for your formula.

You can consider [optim](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html) or one of its extensions for your problem.